# How to count sub string with specific regulation?

Tags: python

Assuming a string like this

```
a1:b1:c1:d1#a2:b2:c2:d2#a3:b3:c3:d3#......#
```

`a,b,c,d` are all long int, and `a(i)` may be same as `a(j)`

Now I wonder how many different kinds of c are there?

Additionally, such a string is an object in my dataframe.

Comment: So you are saying that you have a `string` where there are hash delimited groups of exactly 4 integers?

Comment: `len(set(x.split(':')[-2] for x in my_string.split('#')))`?

Comment: @quamrana correct！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
len(set(x.split(':')[2] for x in my_string.split('#')))
```

- split the string on the hashes (`"#"`) to get the individual 4-integer groups
- split each group on the colons (`":"`) to get the integer (represented as a string). `c`s are on index 2.
- "different kinds": use a set that automatically neglects duplicates
- get the length of the set to count the individual `c`s

Comment: @quamrana I initially somehow thought that OP needed the `d`s so I was using `-1` and then realized that it was the `c`s and changed the number only from `-1` to `-2`. Will update

Comment: Excellent!! You just saved my day

Comment: @Garvey You are exaggerating things a bit but happy to help! xD